# How to get small value in specific range

Tags: excel, vba, range, worksheet-function

[image]

I want to get 1st,2nd,3rd,...nth...small values in **dates** which are on **column D**. but there was a specific **category** which is shown in **column E**. I wrote a code to get a specific range call p. and it is working. that means when category C it selects only C values in the range. when it is equal F it gets only F values.

Now I want to get a row number of 1st small value. but category C it gives correct small value. but it becomes category F it again gave the previous results. can anyone help me with this problem.?

```
dim p as range, c as range, i as integer, irow as long
dim ary(1 to 5) as varient 

ary(1) = "C"
ary(2) = "F"
ary(3) = "B"
ary(4) = "PC"
ary(5) = "BC"

For i = 1 To UBound(ary)
cat = ary(i)
Set p = Nothing
Set c = Nothing
    For Each c In Range("E: E")
        If c.Value = cat Then
            If p Is Nothing Then
                Set p = c.Offset()
            Else
            Set p = Union(p, c)
            End If
        End If
    Next c

irow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Small(p.Offset(, -1), 1), Range("D:D"), 0)
Cells(4, 12) = Cells(irow, 5)
next i
```

Comment: `varient ` -> `Variant`: how can your code debug (and run)?

Comment: and you can use [`Small()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.small), like `WorksheetFunction.Small (p, 1)`

Comment: `Set p = c.Offset()` doesn't make any sense. Change it to `Set p = c` • Also note that you cannot `p.Offset(, -1)` if `p` consists of non-continous cells which is possible because of `Set p = Union(p, c)`. The code will fail to offset then. Instead you need to offset **before** yous use `union`.

Comment: @HTH the p range assign to column E, but i want to get small value in column D. that's why i used `p.offset(,-1)`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ assigning p range process was successfully worked. problem is a program run in 2nd time in the loop which that is equal i=2, that small value didn't change. in i=2, the p range is successfully assigned to F values.

Comment: yes, it worked maybe, but only by accident. Whenever `Union` collects 2 cells that are not consecutive your code does not work. So you need to fix that first. See my last comment again. • Further check if `p.Offset(, -1).Address` is what you expect. Then check if `WorksheetFunction.Small(p.Offset(, -1), 1)` is the result you expect. This way go step by step to debug your code. You can use `Debug.Print` to get the values. Check out [Excel Easy - Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html)